# How to stop a WAV clip in JAVA from playing

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am trying to stop an intro song from playing when pressing the start button. I tried doing so using this code. Note that this code does not entail all my code. The GUI looks fine, the Actionlisteners work fine too. Only **the music does not stop playing when the start button is pressed**.

```
File introPath = new File("src/BattleshipGUI/423499__soundflakes__epic-heroic-orchestral- 
                                                                      dramatic.wav");
File buttonPressedPath = new File("src/BattleshipGUI/sfx_patcher_button_launch.wav");
static Clip introWAV;


    Menu() {


    super("BattleBoard");


    this.setContentPane(this.panelMain);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.pack();
    
    play(introPath); // playing when launching 


    // when the game starts, the sound should stop

    ButtonStartGame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
            play(buttonPressedPath);

            try {
                if (random) {

                    currentCols = (Integer) spinnerColumns.getValue();
                    currentRows = (Integer) spinnerRows.getValue();
                    if (currentCols < 5 || currentRows < 5) {
                        
                        throw (new IllegalArgumentException());
                    } else {
                        BoardFrame b = new BoardFrame(currentRows, currentCols);
                        b.SetFrame(currentRows, currentCols);
                        b.AddRandomShips(currentRows, currentCols);
                        b.ScoreMethod(adjustedScoreMethod);
                        introWAV.stop();
                        introWAV.flush();
                        introWAV.close();
                        dispose();



public static void SetIntroWAV(Clip clip){

    introWAV=clip;
}

public static void play(File file) {
    try {
        Clip sound = AudioSystem.getClip();
        sound.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
        SetIntroWAV(sound);
        sound.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I tried other ways, like using while loops in the Play-class, 'if-else'-statements,... Does someone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is part of your `play` method.
Whenever you want to play *any* sound you also call `SetIntroWAV` internally. This results in your `introWAV` variable being set.

Here's why that's a problem:
The first time you call `play`, your intro sound is played back and `introWAV` has the correct value.
However, once you start your game and play a different sound (namely using `buttonPressedPath`) your `introWAV` variable is set to a different value: the sound that was most recently started.
When you then try to stop your sound from playing, you're using `introWAV` which doesn't *actually* contain a reference to your intro sound anymore. Instead, this will result in your most recently played sound to be stopped since this is what `introWAV` is holding now.

To fix this, it's simply a case of only setting your `introWAV` variable once and not every time `play` is called. There are multiple ways of doing this, including these:

1. You could let your `play` method return the resulting `Clip` that will be played afterwards:

   ```
   public static Clip play(File file) {
       Clip sound = null;
       try {
           sound = AudioSystem.getClip();
           sound.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
           sound.start();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
       } finally {
           return sound;
       }
   }
   ```

You can then use this returned value to call `SetIntroWAV` once: `SetIntroWAV(play(introPath));`
You could also use this return value for other purposes like keeping local references to your sounds. However, you don't have to use it every time and can still ignore it whenever you don't need that reference.

2. You could rewrite your `play` method to also contain a parameter telling the method whether the sound you're trying to play is the intro sound:

   ```
   public static void play(File file, boolean intro) {
       try {
           Clip sound = AudioSystem.getClip();
           sound.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
           if(intro) {
               SetIntroWAV(sound);
           }
           sound.start();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
       }
   }
   ```

This will also result in `SetIntroWAV` only being called once.

I'd also recommend you use more of an object-oriented style of programming for this as it can make things like these much more obvious and easier to fix.
For example, you could create separate classes for audio playback and your gameplay.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best practice with `Clip` variables is to load and open, and then hold them in memory. This can be done in a class that manages your sound effects. In that class, have a Clip as an instance variable and preload and open it in the constructor.

This class can also have two methods that are called from your game.

```
public void play() {
    clip.setFramePosition(0); // ensures Clip will start from the beginning
    clip.start();
}

public void stop() {
    clip.stop();
}
```

With this sort of structure, it also become easier to manage multiple sounds. For example, you can have two instances of this sound-managing class, and set each to a different sound source. Then, you can readily stop one and start another.